# How to delete multiple files from SPO using PowerAutomate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I'm using SharePoint Online ModernUI.
I could delete multiple item from List using PowerAutomate's 'Get Items' action.
But it's for list only.
I'd like to do the same for files and folders in the document library.
Do you have any ideas on which action in PowerAutomate to use for my requirement.

Appreciate any ideas\Pointers. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldnt you use the "Get files" SharePoint action? And then Apply to Each file and delete file?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your information.
But I cannot set identifier in Delete file action.Do you know how to set identifier?